# how to fit all input element in parent div using css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have below html tags and i want to fit all input element inside parent div in single line (responsive) using css3 currently its working but with jquery code.
can anybody help me to create css3 or less formula for this parent div width divided on each child element

```
       <div class="row actualDiv">  
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
                <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
        </div>
```

and i have below jquery code

```
var Totalwidth = parseInt($('.actualDiv').css('width').replace('px', ''));
    var $child = $('.actualDiv').find('input[type="text"]');
    var eachwidth = Totalwidth / $child.length;
    $child.css('width', eachwidth + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

If you can use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), then its possible to achieve by css. Just note its not support by all browsers: [caniuse-flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
.actualDiv {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.actualDiv input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row actualDiv">  
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
   <input typeof="text" placeholder="P1-D1" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: i don't want to use jquery/javascript i want to handle this in css

Comment: @MUHAMMADMUBUSHERASLAM changed to a css solution.

Comment: Thanks @fuyushimoya, i have another question how can i keep the border on top of focused input i tried below but it doesn't work for me, any suggestion

input[type=text]:focus {
        border: 5px solid black !important;
        z-index:1000;
    }

Comment: You may have to ask in another question and create a demo to demonstrate, is there any [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for it. I'm not sure I get what you said about the border.

Comment: You mean, you only want the border at top, not left right bottom? I see the thickened border on focused input from your jsfiddle. If it is, you can specifiy each dir's border, like `border-top/border-left`... like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/y36r1aca/3/).